# ReactJS - Hide a div with specific background image

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have this React Component

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'    
    import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';    

    const LightBoxTest = () => (

      <div>

        <Lightbox images={[
          {
            src: '../images/pic_01.jpg'       
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_03.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
          src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'  
          }
        ]} />
      </div>
    );
```

This dependence 'react-lightbox-component' renders two css classes: one for the images thumbnails and another one for each enlarged image: 'lightbox-image' class. When the images are enlarged after the clicking, they are transformed into a Div and its scr transformed into a background-image.

How do I remove this class for all images which one contains 'decorative.jpg' in its background-image?

I want to do it because I do NOT want these images named 'decorative.jpg' to be enlarged. I want they only as thumbnails. How can I solve it?

Comment: I solve the enlarged image to NOT appear with these CSS rules:

.lightbox-image[style*='decorative'] {
  display:none;
}

Now the images don't appear but the arrows of respective image continues there by showing like transparent images. How can I solve it?

Comment: I would use a different approach than CSS for your example. On their example page you can manually bind the function to the thumbnails. I would disable that, and not adding CSS rules to hide content

Comment: be more specific showing the code please

Comment: I will, I just have to create a project on my machine because react-lightbox-component does not have a cdnjs to work with it in jsFiddle

Comment: Thank you I will be here waiting while I'm working on the computer trying to solve other issues.

Comment: do you add a CSS resource manually or something else beside the `npm install react-lightbox-component` ? The CSS of the component does not work for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188599/discussion-between-sabbin-and-claudiobitar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using their example, in order to disable click on an thumbnail you could use the following code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

class LightBoxTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [
          {
            src: '../images/pic_01.jpg'       
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_02.jpg'
          },
          {
            src: '../images/pic_03.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
            src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'        
          },
          {
          src: '../images/decorative_pic.jpg'  
          }
       ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { images } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <Lightbox
          images={images}
          renderImageFunc={(idx, image, toggleLightbox, width, height) => {
            let onClick = () => null;
            const patt = /decorative/g;
            if(!patt.test(image.src)) onClick = toggleLightbox.bind(null, idx);
            return (
              <img
                key={idx}
                src={image.src}
                style={{width: width, height: height}}
                onClick={onClick} />
            )
          }}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LightBoxTest;
```

Here, in the render method you can manually bind the action for the thumbnail, in your case there is a regex that checks if the image file src contains the word `decorative` and if it does it `returns` null at the `onClick` event handler, if not the image will open.

> **LE**

I've modified the first example to fit your needs...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Lightbox from 'react-lightbox-component';

class LightBoxTest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [
        {
          src: '../images/pic_01.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: '../images/pic_02.jpg'
        },
        {
          src: '../images/pic_03.jpg'
        }
      ]
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { images } = this.state;
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection:'row' }}>
        <div>
          <Lightbox
            images={images}
            thumbnailWidth='150px'
            thumbnailHeight='150px'
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="../images/decorative_pic.jpg" style={{ width: '150px', height: '150px' }} />
          <img src="../images/decorative_pic.jpg" style={{ width: '150px', height: '150px' }} />
          <img src="../images/decorative_pic.jpg" style={{ width: '150px', height: '150px' }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default LightBoxTest;
```

Comment: Thank you I will try to implement your solution, then I will be back to mark your answer as right or ask another thing

Comment: It didn't work at all. It oly blocked the clicking of the decoratives images. I was solve it before with these css rules:  img[src*='decorative']{
  cursor:default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
But your solution is continuing show the enlarged decorative images

Comment: Actually, when you click on the decorative image nothing happens, in the right way, but when you move in the slider and click on the left arrows, they begin to appear.

Comment: When the image is enlarged it is transformed into a div with the 'src' transformed into a 'background-image'. How I commented before, I inserted these other css rules .lightbox-image[style*='decorative'] // <--cathing the div bg-image//  {
  display:none; 
} and it showed  transparent images flowing in the slide while you click on the arrow

Comment: What you want is to ignore the images... so let's say you have in this order: `img1` `img2` `decorative` `img3`... so when you press next from `img2` should go directly to `img3` not to the `decorative`. Is this true?

Comment: The decorative images ever will appear in the end. Never between other images.

Comment: so why do you put them in the lightbox then? why don't you just display them as regular `<img>` and set the same `style` as the thumbnails? That way it will look the same but you will not have any behaviour from the `lightbox` related to them

Comment: I did it this way because the component distributed the images well and put the decorative images to fill in the remaining blanks, but any idea to improve the logic can be valid. For example I have space for 8 images, but I only have 5 images The program dynamically places image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, decorative, decorative, decorative

Comment: The idea is reproduce it:
http://www.maurobitar.com.br/interiores7.html

Comment: I get what you are trying to do now. But I don't think that this plugin is the right one, because you cannot disable the `next` and `prev` actions for specific images...

Comment: Thank you I will let this way with transparent divs.

Comment: when they are enlarged

Comment: If you want the exact layout like in that one, but with 6 images I would still use the Lightbox only for the ones that work and the rest I would use plain `<img>` with the same `style` props as the `thumbnails` so in that way they all look the same in `style` but the decorative ones don't have any behaviour

Comment: Thank you I will try to do this way

Comment: I've edited the response and added the new code. Try that and see if it works

Comment: also you can remove the `renderImageFunc` prop from `Lightbox` component since we don't do anything there any more... I removed it from the code in the answer also

Comment: This solution didn't work. I showed the simplest version of the code. I have another one more complex that renders the images in a dynamic way and cover the blank spaces with decorative images. I will update the component code. It could have some idea to improve it.

Comment: The answer is based on your initial code. I cannot guess what other code you have.. you can adapt the answer as you need. But in the plain version of the component the code works...

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do it. I will mark your solution as right